# Interactive assumptions not falsifiable?

Tags: encryption

Can someone explain why an interactive assumption is not falsifiable? Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the statement means, but isn't even a non-interactive assumption interactive, but just with a zero amount of interaction?

There is no context here, just this isolated paragraph in the intro of a paper:

> Due to a series of criticisms starting with [CGH98] more and more
>   practical schemes are being proposed and proved secure in the standard
>   model (i.e., without random oracles) and under falsifiable (and thus
>   non-interactive) assumptions.

The paper never mentions this again. Neither does it define the term falsifiable.

Comment: Can you give us more context? Did you read this in a paper or book? A link to the material with relevant quotes pasted into the question would be very helpful.

Comment: See also the same question on Theoretical Computer Science SE http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/27763/8067 .  When cross-posting, please link the questions both ways in the future.

Comment: The term "falsifiable assumption" is defined for example in Gentry and Wichs, *Separating Succinct Non-Interactive Arguments From All Falsifiable Assumptions* ([link](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/610)). I'm not sure what an "interactive assumption" is, however.

Comment: Don't cross post. It is against SE rules.